# Could a skydiver levitate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, free-fall

A diver exits his plane and with decreasing acceleration, eventually reaches terminal V owing to Weight=Friction. Then he opens his chute, and friction>weight, so he decelerates (up). My question is, if the diver had enough time before he hit the ground, could he reach a point where he would be completely stationary?

{Assuming uniform air density}

Comment: Of course this does not consider paragliding, where they use hot air and wind rising on a cliff face to rise up in the air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless his parachute is lighter than air.

The parachute creates a new exponential decay to a lower terminal velocity, but due to the nature of the drag equation, it can only ever oppose the relative motion.  As soon as you stop moving, no matter how high the drag force when moving, the restive force will be zero again, and you will begin to fall.

At very best, you can slow your terminal velocity down to *approximately* $0$, but never actually reach it (and that would require a *very* large parachute).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. According to the [drag equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation) the drag force is proportional to the skydiver's surface area and to the square of velocity. After the parachute opens the drag force increases to higher than the skydiver's weight, causing deceleration. However, the decrease in velocity results in a decrease in drag force, until the force balances the weight once more.

The skydiver with an open parachute will, given enough time, settle at a new terminal velocity lower than that without the parachute.